# Multitouch ripple effect - CSS3 / Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to get a "ripple effect on touch" working with multi touch.

This example here for instance works perfect with mouse and single touch: (But not multi touch)
https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Material-Design-Style-Click-Touch-Animations-with-jQuery-CSS3/
Documentation:
https://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/Material-Design-Style-Click-Touch-Animations-with-jQuery-CSS3.html

```
  var left = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
  var top = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
  $(this).append(
    '<div class="dot" style="top:' + top + "px;left:" + left + 'px;"></div>'
  );
```

when I tried this, it worked with 2 fingers (and only that)

```
  var left = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
  var top = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;
  var left1 = e.originalEvent.touches[1].pageX;
  var top1 = e.originalEvent.touches[1].pageY;
  $(this).append(
    '<div class="dot" style="top:' + top + "px;left:" + left + 'px;"></div>'
  );
  $(this).append(
    '<div class="dot" style="top:' + top1 + "px;left:" + left1 + 'px;"></div>'
  );
```

Then I tried it with for loops but can't get it to work.
Whats the best and most efficient way to solve this?

**EDIT**

Seems I messed up twice.

1. I used an old modernizr CDN without the touch feature
2. Modernizr.touchevents is current instead of Modernizr.touch

With that corrected it works:
https://codepen.io/p33k/pen/WNrxOBg

But is this a good solution like this or can it be optimized?